# HTTP 204 No-content error in ASP.NET CORE POST-Request

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, http, postman

Hi fellow programmers,

I am using POSTMAN to check my HTTP POST-Request to my ASP.NET CORE API-method. The method should only return the JSON-string that is given as a paremeter (for testing), but I keep getting null.

MY JSON looks like this:

```
{
 "car": {
    "licenseplate": "XX-XXX-X",
    "make": "Audi",
    "model": "A7",
    "year": 2017,
    "fueltype": 1,
    "available": true
    }
}
```

MY API-function looks like this:

```
// POST: api/API
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromBody]string json)
    {
        return json;
    }
```

The error I am getting is a 204 No-content, which would mean that the returned json is null, but I am clearly sending JSON.

Thanks in advance for helping.

UPDATE (Right answer):

the following JSON should have been used:

```
{
    "contractID": "1",
    "licenseplate": "XX-XXX-X",
    "make": "Audi",
    "model": "A7",
    "year": 2017,
    "fueltype": 1,
    "available": true
}
```

"car" was unnecessary and the accepted answer stated i should return the model instead of a string, since it is a JSON-object and not a string.

Comment: did you try to do anything at all? Set a breakpoint inside your method to see what you receive in your json string? The first thing when something does not work is to start debugging

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu yes of course i debugged.. it works if i just post a string, it will return the string. I also checked if the string is valid Json with JsonLinter, which it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During model binding, ASP.NET is trying to bind your json data to the `string` datatype. However, your json is not a valid json string, but a json object. A json string would have been `"this is a string"`. Therefore, the `json` parameter would have returned you `null`.

You need to define a class for your model:

```
public class Car 
{
    public string Licenseplate { get; set; }
    ... 
}
```

And then, your API:

```
[HttpPost]
public string Post([FromBody]Car car)
{
    return car.Licenseplate;
}
```

Comment: You might actually be right, got a 200 now, but all values are null. Any idea why?

Comment: In postman, did you ensure that the `Content-type` header is set to `application/json`?